# iPhone UIImageView Array

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, nsarray

So I'm declaring a NSMutableArray to hold 5 UIImageViews.

.h file:

```
@interface ImageDisplay : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *img1;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *img2;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *img3;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *img4;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *img5;
    NSMutableArray *imageHolderArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *img1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *img2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *img3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *img4;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *img5;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSMutableArray *imageHolderArray;
@end
```

In the .m file:

```
//All objects are synthesized, just easier not to crowd the screen

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imageHolderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,nil];
    NSLog(@"imageHolderArray count: %i",[imageHolderArray count]); //Returns count of 1
}
```

So my question is, why is this happening? Why isn't it picking up all the objects in the Array? I'm not well versed in Objective-C programming so I'd appreciate it if someone could clue me in here.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you certain that none of the imgN references are nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't wire the IBOutlets to their views in Interface Builder. Looks like you probably wired `img1`, but didn't wire `img2`, so `img2` is `nil`, which marks the end of your list of objects for `-initWithObjects:` even if later outlets are wired.